# Difference between offset and RVA

Tags: exe, portable-executable

What is the difference between a relative virtual address and an offset from the base of a file??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RVA is the relative-virtual address, that is, the distance from the preferred base address.  The preferred base address is stated in the PE header, and is the (preferred) virtual address of the start of the image in memory for when the executable be loaded in memory.

And the  file offset is the number of bytes you have to read from the beginning of the PE file to arrive somewhere in the file. So, if you have a section, you will find both things in the section header: the RVA of the section and its offset in the file; you will also find two sizes, one for how much virtual memory the section will get once loaded and one that merely indicates the size of the section data in the PE file.

Many references inside a PE are given as RVAs. In such cases, you need to check in all the section headers (or have some sort of map) to get the offset in the PE file of the reference.

Comment: Is there some other way of converting an rva into an offset?

Comment: Whats the difference between a Relative virtual Address and a Virtual Address?

Comment: For converting an rva to an offset, you have to go through the section headers with your rva on hand until you find a section whose rva range, as given by the fields "virtual_address" and "virtual_size", encompass your rva.

Comment: Hey dsign, just wanna ask you one more thing, I am not quiet sure about this so may be you could help..

When the loader loads a program into the memory for execution, does each program begin with a virtual address of 0, or does it begin with the physical address at which it is loaded into the RAM? I hope you understand what am trying to ask..

Comment: An rva is "relative" to the base address. The base addres is the preferred load address of the image, and is given in the optional headers of the PE. Check this file for an example of PE tinkering: http://alcides-mp.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=2

Comment: I'm not sure about where the program is loaded, but my intuition is that the loader will put it wherever it fits: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Relocations